# Signed distance field calculation bug

Tags: c, graphics

I am writing an small utility to compute [signed distance field](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf) textures for a graphic application. I am doing true signed distance fields, not approximations, so I first transform each glyph path to an arc spline to speed up point-to-path distance computations. Problem is that I am getting strange artifacts on some corners:

[image: Signed distance field of glyph A from DejaVuSerif]

Path is extracted from an [EPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) generated by [FontForge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FontForge) without any manipulation. Distance is computed finding minimum distance from each pixel coordinates to any path line segment or arc (three nested loops: `for (x;...) { for (y; ...) { for (i; ...) { ... }}}`). Computed per-pixel distance is iterated to extract minimum and maximum values and rescaled to 0-255 range and written directly to a raw image file and coverted to [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) with [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick).

The only source of this bug I can think is a numerical error inside the function used to compute point-to-segment distance. Here it is:

```
double dist_to_segment(double px, double py, /* query point */
                       double x0, double y0, /* first segment end-point */
                       double x1, double y1) /* second segment end-point */
{
  const double t0 = dist2(x0, y0, x1, y1);
  if (t0 == 0.0) { return dist2(px, py, x0, x1); }
  const double t1 = dot(px-x0, py-y0, x1-x0, y1-y0)/t0;
  const double t2 = clamp(t1, 0.0, 1.0);
  const double t3 = sqrt(dist2(px, py, lerp(x0,x1,t2), lerp(y0,y1,t2)));
  const double t4 = (x1-x0)*(py-y0) - (y1-y0)*(px-x0);
  return (t4 < 0.0)? -t3 : t3;
}
```

Where `dot`, `clamp`, `lerp` are defined as in OpenGL shading language and `dist2` is defined as:

```
double dist2(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
{
  return (x0-x1)*(x0-x1) + (y0-y1)*(y0-y1);
}
```

If I replace `return (t4 < 0.0)? -t3 : t3;` with `return t3;` on `dist_to_segment` I get this unsigned distance field:

[image: Unsigned distance field of glyph A from DejaVuSerif]

**EDIT**

I solved small triangle-shaped artifacts adding a point-in-polygon test to the already existing edge iterating loop, so extra cost is not to high. Sharp features along the bisectors of acute angles though. There is new sample image.

[image: New result]

Comment: Have you ruled out round-off errors?

Comment: @ScottHunter Only round is happening in my code is converting distance from `double` to `uint8_t` with a safety `clamp(x, 0.0, 255.0)` before it. This can't be the source of the problem.

Comment: So you're computing the shortest distance from point (px, py) to the line segment with endpoints (x0, y0), (x1, y1)?

Comment: Could you provide `dist2()` implementation and how `dist_to_segment()` is called including the types of the parameters passed.  Does `dot()` take `double` arguments?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, this is what `dist_to_segment` is supposed to do, but it looks like some of the segment endpoints get moved, enlarging it, and causing this problem. There is no manipulation to segment points though...

Comment: Definitively is a problem of inside/outside determination. For some reason there are small areas where it is computed the opposite (i.e. sign is wrong).

Comment: If you draw the region where `t4` is zero or small in magnitude, say `return 255.0 * (t4 > -0.001 && t4 < 0.001);` (which is 255.0 if `t4` is near zero, 0.0 elsewhere), you will get a superset of the anomalous regions (i.e., anomalous regions, plus possibly some other small regions). This means your logic `t4 < 0.0` is incorrect; that test does not map to *"inside the glyph polygon"*.

Comment: @NominalAnimal This seems to be the problem. Now I'm using maximum of absolute distance to determine pixel region. Although it works for most places, obviously it doesn't on all of them.

Comment: Just out of interest, could you check if the anomalies persist if you change the return statement into `return ((x1-x0)*(py-y0) <= (y1-y0)*(px-x0)) ? -t3 : t3;`? I don't think it will fix it, but if it fails in different regions, it might be interesting..

Comment: @NominalAnimal With `<=` comparison it fails completely (I think because my current point region selection). With `<` comparison it produces same result.

Comment: Could you see if skipping too-short line segments in the caller -- essentially ignoring line segments for which `t0 < epsilon` for some positive `epsilon` close to zero -- fixes it? You see, I believe it is the *earlier* `return` that gets called in the anomalous regions.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Problem was using minimum of absolute value to determine point-in-polygon. Now I added to the existing edge loop a more robust solution and small triangles are gone, but sharp features are still here.

Comment: Sharp features? If you draw contour curves instead of looking at the grayscale image, you'll see there are no "sharp features". The bisectors may *look* too light, but that's just a perception thing; not an actual data feature. As far as I can see, that is.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Maybe it is a perception problem, accentuated interpreting a linear image as an sRGB one (as is done normally by image viewers). How can I draw contour lines? It is something interesting to do to check output quality.

Comment: Quick hack to see contours: You have 256 grayscale values. Split them into e.g. 16 contour bands of 16 values each. Set say the four first ones to a specific color, and the rest (twelve) to a background color.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, Whether you call them "sharp" features or use some other term, the distance map has values that are too large along the bisectors of external acute angles, and values that are too small along internal acute angles.  These effects are noticeable to my eye only close to the bisectors, so they present a fairly sharp appearance to me, though not as sharp as a discontinuity would be.

Comment: @user3368561, I maintain that the remaining anomalous features of your map very likely arise from how you combine the outputs of different calls to your function, not from the function itself.  I think you should consider asking a separate question about them, since the original problem has now been resolved.  Whether you post a new question or not, however, we'll need to see more code to help you troubleshoot the remaining problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Where? I converted the 256 gray levels in the last image above to 16 bands with white in between, and received [this image](http://nominal-animal.net/answers/signed-distance-contour.png). (It is the same image, except that each gray level is mapped to either white or to a color somewhere between red and blue.) There are no values that are too large or too small along the bisectors at all. The reason you *perceive* that in the grayscale image is psychovisual, one of those quirks of human vision.

Comment: Ok, @NominalAnimal, I concede, but it's pretty darn striking for a psychovisual effect.  I suppose it arises from the direction of the gradient of the distance map being discontinuous along the angle bisectors.  The question remains whether a distance map that produces such a psychovisual effect is in fact desirable for the OP's purpose, and what to do about it if not, but that would be better pursued in a separate SO question.

Comment: It is a very strong effect indeed! I've been trying to find references to it, but I just cannot recall the correct terms to find any (luminance gradient edge something?). The effect is easy to describe: when two linear luminance gradients (regions where light intensity changes linearly) intersect, the peak appears much too light (or too dark), depending on the direction of the gradient. It's somehow related to human edge perception, if I recall correctly. I often color-map the gray levels to view those contours, to avoid being tricked by my own perception.

Comment: I [added a recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43644786/1475978) for how I like to remap grayscale levels to color contour curves. It's not an answer, but it was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: Note that my output image is in linear raw format, converted to PNG with ImageMagick without any explicit color map conversion. I'm not sure, but maybe it is not converted to sRGB and explorer image viewer decodes as it was.

Comment: @user3368561: I assume the image size is 1024×1024. If you have a 1048576-byte raw 8-bit grayscale data, you can make it into a PGM file by prepending `P5\n1024 1024 255\n` (17 bytes, `\n` referring to ASCII code 13) to it. If you have 2097152 bytes of 16-bit grayscale data, make it `P5\n1024 1024 65535\n` (19 bytes), but note that you do need to extend my script as it only handles 8-bit grayscale in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment, to show how to convert gray levels to contours using netpbm tools. From OP's last image, this yields [image: this]

The following Bash script uses `ppmchange` to remap the exact color values to color bands separated by white:

```
#!/bin/bash
colormap=()
for ((i = 0; i < 256; i++)); do
    colormap+=( $(printf '#%02x%02x%02x' $i $i $i) )
    if (( (i & 15) < 6 )); then
        colormap+=( $(printf '#%02x00%02x' $[(i/16)*17] $[255-(i/16)*17]) )
    else
        colormap+=( "#ffffff" )
    fi
done
exec ppmchange -closeness 0 ${colormap[@]} "$@"
```

I like to call it `gray-to-contour`.  If you want to specify the exact colors, you can use

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ppmchange -closeness 0 \
    '#000000' '#0000ff' \
    '#010101' '#0000ff' \
    '#020202' '#0000ff' \
    '#030303' '#0000ff' \
    '#040404' '#0000ff' \
    '#050505' '#0000ff' \
    '#060606' '#ffffff' \
    '#070707' '#ffffff' \
    '#080808' '#ffffff' \
    '#090909' '#ffffff' \
    '#0a0a0a' '#ffffff' \
    '#0b0b0b' '#ffffff' \
    '#0c0c0c' '#ffffff' \
    '#0d0d0d' '#ffffff' \
    '#0e0e0e' '#ffffff' \
    '#0f0f0f' '#ffffff' \
    '#101010' '#1100ee' \
    '#111111' '#1100ee' \
    '#121212' '#1100ee' \
    '#131313' '#1100ee' \
    '#141414' '#1100ee' \
    '#151515' '#1100ee' \
    '#161616' '#ffffff' \
    '#171717' '#ffffff' \
    '#181818' '#ffffff' \
    '#191919' '#ffffff' \
    '#1a1a1a' '#ffffff' \
    '#1b1b1b' '#ffffff' \
    '#1c1c1c' '#ffffff' \
    '#1d1d1d' '#ffffff' \
    '#1e1e1e' '#ffffff' \
    '#1f1f1f' '#ffffff' \
    '#202020' '#2200dd' \
    '#212121' '#2200dd' \
    '#222222' '#2200dd' \
    '#232323' '#2200dd' \
    '#242424' '#2200dd' \
    '#252525' '#2200dd' \
    '#262626' '#ffffff' \
    '#272727' '#ffffff' \
    '#282828' '#ffffff' \
    '#292929' '#ffffff' \
    '#2a2a2a' '#ffffff' \
    '#2b2b2b' '#ffffff' \
    '#2c2c2c' '#ffffff' \
    '#2d2d2d' '#ffffff' \
    '#2e2e2e' '#ffffff' \
    '#2f2f2f' '#ffffff' \
    '#303030' '#3300cc' \
    '#313131' '#3300cc' \
    '#323232' '#3300cc' \
    '#333333' '#3300cc' \
    '#343434' '#3300cc' \
    '#353535' '#3300cc' \
    '#363636' '#ffffff' \
    '#373737' '#ffffff' \
    '#383838' '#ffffff' \
    '#393939' '#ffffff' \
    '#3a3a3a' '#ffffff' \
    '#3b3b3b' '#ffffff' \
    '#3c3c3c' '#ffffff' \
    '#3d3d3d' '#ffffff' \
    '#3e3e3e' '#ffffff' \
    '#3f3f3f' '#ffffff' \
    '#404040' '#4400bb' \
    '#414141' '#4400bb' \
    '#424242' '#4400bb' \
    '#434343' '#4400bb' \
    '#444444' '#4400bb' \
    '#454545' '#4400bb' \
    '#464646' '#ffffff' \
    '#474747' '#ffffff' \
    '#484848' '#ffffff' \
    '#494949' '#ffffff' \
    '#4a4a4a' '#ffffff' \
    '#4b4b4b' '#ffffff' \
    '#4c4c4c' '#ffffff' \
    '#4d4d4d' '#ffffff' \
    '#4e4e4e' '#ffffff' \
    '#4f4f4f' '#ffffff' \
    '#505050' '#5500aa' \
    '#515151' '#5500aa' \
    '#525252' '#5500aa' \
    '#535353' '#5500aa' \
    '#545454' '#5500aa' \
    '#555555' '#5500aa' \
    '#565656' '#ffffff' \
    '#575757' '#ffffff' \
    '#585858' '#ffffff' \
    '#595959' '#ffffff' \
    '#5a5a5a' '#ffffff' \
    '#5b5b5b' '#ffffff' \
    '#5c5c5c' '#ffffff' \
    '#5d5d5d' '#ffffff' \
    '#5e5e5e' '#ffffff' \
    '#5f5f5f' '#ffffff' \
    '#606060' '#660099' \
    '#616161' '#660099' \
    '#626262' '#660099' \
    '#636363' '#660099' \
    '#646464' '#660099' \
    '#656565' '#660099' \
    '#666666' '#ffffff' \
    '#676767' '#ffffff' \
    '#686868' '#ffffff' \
    '#696969' '#ffffff' \
    '#6a6a6a' '#ffffff' \
    '#6b6b6b' '#ffffff' \
    '#6c6c6c' '#ffffff' \
    '#6d6d6d' '#ffffff' \
    '#6e6e6e' '#ffffff' \
    '#6f6f6f' '#ffffff' \
    '#707070' '#770088' \
    '#717171' '#770088' \
    '#727272' '#770088' \
    '#737373' '#770088' \
    '#747474' '#770088' \
    '#757575' '#770088' \
    '#767676' '#ffffff' \
    '#777777' '#ffffff' \
    '#787878' '#ffffff' \
    '#797979' '#ffffff' \
    '#7a7a7a' '#ffffff' \
    '#7b7b7b' '#ffffff' \
    '#7c7c7c' '#ffffff' \
    '#7d7d7d' '#ffffff' \
    '#7e7e7e' '#ffffff' \
    '#7f7f7f' '#ffffff' \
    '#808080' '#880077' \
    '#818181' '#880077' \
    '#828282' '#880077' \
    '#838383' '#880077' \
    '#848484' '#880077' \
    '#858585' '#880077' \
    '#868686' '#ffffff' \
    '#878787' '#ffffff' \
    '#888888' '#ffffff' \
    '#898989' '#ffffff' \
    '#8a8a8a' '#ffffff' \
    '#8b8b8b' '#ffffff' \
    '#8c8c8c' '#ffffff' \
    '#8d8d8d' '#ffffff' \
    '#8e8e8e' '#ffffff' \
    '#8f8f8f' '#ffffff' \
    '#909090' '#990066' \
    '#919191' '#990066' \
    '#929292' '#990066' \
    '#939393' '#990066' \
    '#949494' '#990066' \
    '#959595' '#990066' \
    '#969696' '#ffffff' \
    '#979797' '#ffffff' \
    '#989898' '#ffffff' \
    '#999999' '#ffffff' \
    '#9a9a9a' '#ffffff' \
    '#9b9b9b' '#ffffff' \
    '#9c9c9c' '#ffffff' \
    '#9d9d9d' '#ffffff' \
    '#9e9e9e' '#ffffff' \
    '#9f9f9f' '#ffffff' \
    '#a0a0a0' '#aa0055' \
    '#a1a1a1' '#aa0055' \
    '#a2a2a2' '#aa0055' \
    '#a3a3a3' '#aa0055' \
    '#a4a4a4' '#aa0055' \
    '#a5a5a5' '#aa0055' \
    '#a6a6a6' '#ffffff' \
    '#a7a7a7' '#ffffff' \
    '#a8a8a8' '#ffffff' \
    '#a9a9a9' '#ffffff' \
    '#aaaaaa' '#ffffff' \
    '#ababab' '#ffffff' \
    '#acacac' '#ffffff' \
    '#adadad' '#ffffff' \
    '#aeaeae' '#ffffff' \
    '#afafaf' '#ffffff' \
    '#b0b0b0' '#bb0044' \
    '#b1b1b1' '#bb0044' \
    '#b2b2b2' '#bb0044' \
    '#b3b3b3' '#bb0044' \
    '#b4b4b4' '#bb0044' \
    '#b5b5b5' '#bb0044' \
    '#b6b6b6' '#ffffff' \
    '#b7b7b7' '#ffffff' \
    '#b8b8b8' '#ffffff' \
    '#b9b9b9' '#ffffff' \
    '#bababa' '#ffffff' \
    '#bbbbbb' '#ffffff' \
    '#bcbcbc' '#ffffff' \
    '#bdbdbd' '#ffffff' \
    '#bebebe' '#ffffff' \
    '#bfbfbf' '#ffffff' \
    '#c0c0c0' '#cc0033' \
    '#c1c1c1' '#cc0033' \
    '#c2c2c2' '#cc0033' \
    '#c3c3c3' '#cc0033' \
    '#c4c4c4' '#cc0033' \
    '#c5c5c5' '#cc0033' \
    '#c6c6c6' '#ffffff' \
    '#c7c7c7' '#ffffff' \
    '#c8c8c8' '#ffffff' \
    '#c9c9c9' '#ffffff' \
    '#cacaca' '#ffffff' \
    '#cbcbcb' '#ffffff' \
    '#cccccc' '#ffffff' \
    '#cdcdcd' '#ffffff' \
    '#cecece' '#ffffff' \
    '#cfcfcf' '#ffffff' \
    '#d0d0d0' '#dd0022' \
    '#d1d1d1' '#dd0022' \
    '#d2d2d2' '#dd0022' \
    '#d3d3d3' '#dd0022' \
    '#d4d4d4' '#dd0022' \
    '#d5d5d5' '#dd0022' \
    '#d6d6d6' '#ffffff' \
    '#d7d7d7' '#ffffff' \
    '#d8d8d8' '#ffffff' \
    '#d9d9d9' '#ffffff' \
    '#dadada' '#ffffff' \
    '#dbdbdb' '#ffffff' \
    '#dcdcdc' '#ffffff' \
    '#dddddd' '#ffffff' \
    '#dedede' '#ffffff' \
    '#dfdfdf' '#ffffff' \
    '#e0e0e0' '#ee0011' \
    '#e1e1e1' '#ee0011' \
    '#e2e2e2' '#ee0011' \
    '#e3e3e3' '#ee0011' \
    '#e4e4e4' '#ee0011' \
    '#e5e5e5' '#ee0011' \
    '#e6e6e6' '#ffffff' \
    '#e7e7e7' '#ffffff' \
    '#e8e8e8' '#ffffff' \
    '#e9e9e9' '#ffffff' \
    '#eaeaea' '#ffffff' \
    '#ebebeb' '#ffffff' \
    '#ececec' '#ffffff' \
    '#ededed' '#ffffff' \
    '#eeeeee' '#ffffff' \
    '#efefef' '#ffffff' \
    '#f0f0f0' '#ff0000' \
    '#f1f1f1' '#ff0000' \
    '#f2f2f2' '#ff0000' \
    '#f3f3f3' '#ff0000' \
    '#f4f4f4' '#ff0000' \
    '#f5f5f5' '#ff0000' \
    '#f6f6f6' '#ffffff' \
    '#f7f7f7' '#ffffff' \
    '#f8f8f8' '#ffffff' \
    '#f9f9f9' '#ffffff' \
    '#fafafa' '#ffffff' \
    '#fbfbfb' '#ffffff' \
    '#fcfcfc' '#ffffff' \
    '#fdfdfd' '#ffffff' \
    '#fefefe' '#ffffff' \
    '#ffffff' '#ffffff' "$@"
```

where the left side corresponds to each of the 256 gray levels, and the right side is the corresponding color.

If the original image is `gray.png`, you can create `contour.png` from it using

```
pngtopnm gray.png | ./gray-to-contour | pnmtopng -compress 9 > contour.png
```

As I mentioned in a comment, we humans perceive sharp changes in gradients as edges, and in OP's final image, it only *looks like* the angle bisectors are too light/dark. I tried to locate some references to the effect, but the terms slip by my grasp right now.

While grayscale images are easy to process and use, there are cases where our human psychovisual oddities fool us. For this reason, I personally do look at bump maps and distance fields in both grayscale and contour form; the two representations complement each other, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your function appears correct to me, with the caveat that whether the sign of the result is correct depends on the segment endpoints being ordered according to the correct convention for a path around a boundary of the object.  The images indeed appear to show that it produces correct results. The triangular anomalies near some corners seem likely to be related to how you combine multiple results of this function, rather than to the values returned by any individual call.

In particular, if you add the negative result of a point's distance to one segment to the positive result of a point's distance to a different segment, or if you take the minimum or maximum of the *signed* values of two distances, you will get meaningless results.  Not only the anomalies, but also the sharp features along angle bisectors suggest that you're doing something like this.

The absence of the anomalies from the unsigned distance field is consistent with that analysis, but the persistence into that field of the sharp features along the bisectors of acute angles is curious.  I haven't quite determined what you're doing, but what you *should* be doing is using only each point's distance to the *nearest* edge of the figure.  You must also ensure that your line segments trace each border in the same direction relative to the interior of the figure, as the correct signs of your function's results depend on it.  Additionally, to reproduce the glyph you should render all negative (interior) distances in the same shade.

Comment: Now I'm computing distance from every pixel to all line segments and discard all of them but the closest (maximum of absolute value). This explain small triangle artifacts. It's just a sign mismatch: value is right but of opposite sign. I'm still unable to explain sharp features along the bisectors of acute angles.

Comment: @user3368561, surely the distance to the closest edge is the one with the *minimum*, not maximum, absolute value.  I suspect that's what you actually are doing, however, because if you were doing the opposite then it would be pretty clear that something was wrong.  Nevertheless, the sharp features along the bisectors are not consistent with doing that.  They arise at the places where the distance to one edge is nearly the same as the distance to another, so they reflect some kind of combination of the influence of two or more edges.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I'm using minimum of absolute value, not maximum. I'm getting another strange artifact when I change last `t4 < 0` comparison to `t4 <= 0`: output becomes almost gray (there is a singular value making problems when normalizing to range 0-255).

Answer (score 1):

`double dist_to_segment()` returns inconsistent units.

`return (t4 < 0.0)? -t3 : t3;` and `return t3;` (OP's alternative code) return a *distance*.

`return dist2(px, py, x0, x1);` returns a *distance squared*.  This is used when `(x0,y0)` and `(x1,y1)` are the same or *very* nearly so -perhaps in those pesky corners.  I'd expect `return sqrt(dist2(px, py, x0, x1));`

---

A simplification to `sqrt(a*a + b*b)` is `hypot(a,b)`

> The `hypot` functions compute the square root of the sum of the squares of `x` and `y`, without undue overflow or underflow.  C11 §7.12.7.3 2

```
// example
if (t0 == 0.0) { 
  return hypot(px - x0, py - y0);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. A bug product of premature optimization.